# Using React I am trying to produce three buttons that represent the three collections, and when clicked will take you to that collection of cards

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to import an array of objects from an axios get request, assign a value to three buttons based on the three objects in the array.
I tried .map the array into a button, with a function to pull the object name onClick. It produces three buttons, but when clicked it only produces the last object name that was passed through.
I have tried destructuring the array inside the Collections function, but when I do I get a property name undefined error. When debuging I tried referencing the axios get in the function, but even when I do it does not work.

```
import React from 'react';
import './collections.css';


function Collections (props) {

let coll = props.collection;
let coll1 = [];
let coll2 = [];
let coll3 = [];
[coll1, coll2, coll3] = coll;

    return(
        
<div className='inline-button'>
    <div  className='button'>
      
       {/* {coll.map(coll =>(
          <tr className='button' key={coll.name}>
       <button className='button' onClick={() => props.btn(coll.name)}>{coll.name}</button> 
       
       </tr>
       ))} */}
        <button className='button' onClick={() => props.btn(coll1.name)}>{coll1.name}</button>  
       
     
      </div>
    
  </div>
   
    );
} 




export default Collections;
```

Comment: can you show the whole component? And can you clean up your code? It is hard to read and looks like at least 2 closing tags are missing...

Comment: Updated with whole component.

Comment: can you show what `props.collection` looks like (Did you try to `console.log(props.collection)`?

Comment: It shows an array of three objects.

Array(3)
0: {_id: "608ab61699ee6440388b79fc", name: "History", cardCollection: Array(9), __v: 14}
1: {_id: "608ac84b988f8358acc34495", name: "Science", cardCollection: Array(5), __v: 5}
2: {_id: "608ac93d988f8358acc34496", name: "Linear Algebra", cardCollection: Array(5), __v: 5}
length: 3
__proto__: Array(0)

Comment: what is props.btn supposed to do? Where is that coming from? and why would you need `let coll1 = [];
let coll2 = [];
let coll3 = []; [coll1, coll2, coll3] = coll;` ?

Comment: I was trying to destructure the array and pass it into three buttons individually.

Comment: prop.btn is a function in app.jsx 

   collButton(collName){
       
        let pickedColl = this.state.collection.filter(collName => {
            this.setState({
                choice: collName.cardCollection
            })
            console.log(collName);
        
        return collName;
       })
   
    }

Answer (score 0):

The best way to get help on StackOverflow is to reproduce the whole issue you are facing. The best tool to do this is to make a minimal, reproducible example & show what you've already tried to solve the problem.

```js
const collection = [
  {_id: "608ab61699ee6440388b79fc", name: "History", cardCollection: [], __v: 14},
  {_id: "608ac84b988f8358acc34495", name: "Science", cardCollection: [], __v: 5},
  {_id: "608ac93d988f8358acc34496", name: "Linear Algebra", cardCollection: [], __v: 5}
]

function Collections (props) {
  const coll = props.collection
  return (
    <div>
      {
        coll.map((coll) => {
          return (
            <button
              onClick={() => props.btn(coll.name)}
            >
              {
                coll.name
              }
            </button>
          )
        })
      }
    </div>
  )
}

const App = (props) => {
  function collButton(collName) {
    // just mocking this function
    console.log(collName)
  }
  return (
    <Collections
      collection={props.collection}
      btn={collButton}
    />
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App
    collection={ collection }
  />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

I tried to recreate your environment/context, and everything seems to work out just fine.

Try to avoid calling the item that you iterate over & the iteratee the same name (`coll`) - it's going to be confusing very fast.

But there's a question: in your comments you say that the `props.btn` function is

```
collButton(collName){ let pickedColl = this.state.collection.filter(collName => { this.setState({ choice: collName.cardCollection }) console.log(collName); return collName; }) }
```

This function makes not much sense to me:

```
collButton(collName) {
  // you define pickedColl as the result of a filter on the
  // state: collection, but the filter doesn't return anything,
  // only runs setState on every iteration; also pickedColl is
  // not used anywhere - why did you need it?
  let pickedColl = this.state.collection
    .filter(collName => {
      this.setState({
        choice: collName.cardCollection
      })
      // you log the collName that you passed in
      console.log(collName);
      // you return the collName that you passed in - that means
      // that if collName is not falsy, then the filter function
      // is going to "keep" it in the array
      return collName;
    })
}
```

So, if you wanted to set the state of the parent to hold `cardCollection`, then you might consider the following snippet:

```js
const { useState } = React

const collection = [
  {_id: "608ab61699ee6440388b79fc", name: "History", cardCollection: ['collection 1_1', 'collection 1_2'], __v: 14},
  {_id: "608ac84b988f8358acc34495", name: "Science", cardCollection: ['collection 2_1', 'collection 2_2'], __v: 5},
  {_id: "608ac93d988f8358acc34496", name: "Linear Algebra", cardCollection: ['collection 3_1', 'collection 3_2'], __v: 5}
]

function Collections (props) {
  const coll = props.collection
  return (
    <div>
      {
        coll.map((coll) => {
          return (
            <button
              // pass the cardCollection instead of the name
              onClick={() => props.btn(coll.cardCollection)}
            >
              {
                coll.name
              }
            </button>
          )
        })
      }
    </div>
  )
}

const App = (props) => {
  const [choice, setChoice] = useState([])

  function collButton(cardCollection) {
    // because the cardCollection is the argument of this
    // function, you just update the state with the value
    setChoice(() => cardCollection)
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <Collections
        collection={props.collection}
        btn={collButton}
      />
      Putting out the collection for test purposes:<br />
      {
        choice.join(", ")
      }
    </div>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App
    collection={ collection }
  />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```